# Unable to match password using equalTo property

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation

I want to validate my form using validate.js and match the password. I wrote the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#signup-form").validate({
        rules: {
            "signup-username": {
                required: true,
                minlength: 2
            },

            "signup-firstname": {
                required: true,
                minlength: 2
            },
        "signup-lastname": {
                required: true,
                minlength: 2
            },
        "signup-email": {
                required: true
            },
        "signup-password1": {
                required: true,
                minlength: 5
            },
        "signup-password2": {
               equalTo: "#signup-password1"
            }

        },
        messages: {
            "signup-username": {
                required: "Please, enter a user name",
                minlength: "Minimum userlength should be 2"
            },
            "signup-firstname": {
                required: "Please, enter your first name",
                minlength: "Minimum firstname length should be 2"
            },
            "signup-lastname": {
                required: "Please, enter your last name",
                minlength: "Minimum lastname length should be 2"
            },
            "signup-email": {
                required: "Please, enter a valid email"
            },
            "signup-password1": {
               required: "Please, enter your password",
               minlength: "Minimum password length should be 5"
            },
             "signup-password1":"Password doesn't match."

        }
        submitHandler: function (form)
        {

            alert("form is submitted successfully.");
        }
    });

});
```

I am new to js. Why is it not working. Sometimes I wonder where to put comma and where not. Please help me.

Comment: jezrael appears to have given you the correct answer. See other example here: [Validate.js equalTo](http://jqueryvalidation.org/equalTo-method/)

Comment: `firstname` `minlength: 2` --- **WHAT**? "Your name does not qualify our policies so change it to another one"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try change:

```
"signup-password2": {
           equalTo: "#signup-password2"
        }
```

...

```
"signup-password1":"Password doesn't match."
```

to:

```
"signup-password2": {
           required: true,
           equalTo: "#signup-password1"
        }
```

...

```
"signup-password2": {
            required: "Please, enter your password again",
            equalTo: "Password doesn't match." 
        }
```

[Doc](http://jqueryvalidation.org/equalTo-method/)
[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jyym2n8e/8/)- validate plugin is broken
[another fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/brantolsen/2b5zS/) - works correct

Answer (score 0):

not familiar at all with this library, but I think you mean to check whether `signup-password2` is equal to `signup-password1`. So it should read like:

```
"signup-password2": {
    equalTo: "#signup-password1"
}
```